# jquery expand firlst ul>li>ul of parent

Tags: jquery

i have some jquery thats expanding/collapsing on click. i would like the first item to be expanded by default but im having trouble with the jquery. i've tried a few different angles to no avail. any help would be much appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/trrJp/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep the first item expanded by default with the following line

```
  $('#collapser li:first-child > ul').show();
```

What it does is selects the `first li` and then select the `ul` within that `li` and `show` that.

[First Child Selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/)

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/trrJp/2/)

Comment: ahah! thanks a ton, i don't know how i missed '.show' i was trying to change the css altogether for some reason!

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is only you want the first item to open, after you setup all the menu jquery you can do something like this:

`$('#menu li:first').slideToggle();`

Or you could simulate a click:

`$('#menu li:first').click();`

The actual code is dependent on your actual implementation and how you'd open it but the general idea is to trigger the first element to open.